# Calcuate $\langle x | D | y \rangle$ for arbitrary $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm, textbook-and-exercises

We are considering Grover's algorithm with a search space of size $2^n$ for an arbitrary integer $n$ for arbitrary $n$, and a unique marked element $x_0$.

Question: Calculate $\langle x | D | y \rangle$ for arbitrary $x,y \in \{0,1\}^n$

Answer: Using the expression $D = -(I-2|+^n\rangle\langle+^n|)$, we have

$$\langle x | D | y \rangle =  
     \begin{cases}
       \frac{2}{N}-1 &\quad\text{if x=y}\\
       \frac{2}{N} &\quad\text{if x $\neq$ y} 
     \end{cases}
$$

How has the equality $D = -(I-2|+\rangle\langle+|)$ been derived? Its from these notes [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~csxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ecsxam/teaching/qc2020/lecturenotes.pdf)

How do derive the split function? I cannot see the route to start to evaluate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grover's Diffusion Operator $D$ can be written as $H^{\otimes n}U_0H^{\otimes n}$ where $U_0$ is the following matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & ... &0 
\\.& . & 1 & ... & .
\\.& . & . & ... & .
\\0& 0 & 0 & ... & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$
The unitary $U_0$ has the property that $U_0|0^n\rangle = -|0^n\rangle$ and $U_0|\psi\rangle = -|\psi\rangle$.
Thus unitary $U_0$ can also be written as $2|0^n\rangle\langle0^n|-I$ as its matrix form can be expressed as:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 
\\ 0 & -1 & 0 & ... &0 
\\.& . & -1 & ... & .
\\.& . & . & ... & .
\\0& 0 & 0 & ... & -1
\end{bmatrix} = 2
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 
\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & ... &0 
\\.& . & 0 & ... & .
\\.& . & . & ... & .
\\0& 0 & 0 & ... & 0
\end{bmatrix} -
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 &... & 0 
\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & ... &0 
\\.& . & 1 & ... & .
\\.& . & . & ... & .
\\0& 0 & 0 & ... & 1
\end{bmatrix}   
$$
Now $D$ can be expressed as
$$D=H^{\otimes n}U_0H^{\otimes n}=H^{\otimes n}(2|0^n\rangle\langle0^n|-I)H^{\otimes n}\\
= 2H^{\otimes n}|0^n\rangle\langle0^n|H^{\otimes n}-H^{\otimes n}IH^{\otimes n} \\
= 2(H|0\rangle\langle0|H)^{\otimes n} - I \\
= 2(|+\rangle\langle+|)^{\otimes n} -I \\
= 2|+^n\rangle\langle+^n| -I \\
= -(I - 2|+^n\rangle\langle+^n|)$$

I hope this derivation helps.